# Chain rule for change of variables to get $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d\overline{x}}{dx}\frac{d}{d\overline{x}}$

Tags: calculus

[image]

A change of variable from $x$ to $\overline{x} = \frac{x}{\epsilon^\alpha}$ is done, but I do not understand how they obtain $$\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d\overline{x}}{dx}\frac{d}{d\overline{x}} = \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\alpha}}\frac{d}{d\overline{x}}$$

How is chain-rule applied to the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$? I am familiar with chain rule saying basically: $f'(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine what a function does, supply it an input.  Two functions having the same domain are equal if they give the same output for the same input.

To determine what an operator does, supply it a function.  Two operators (having the same domain) are equal if they give the same output for the same input.

The operator $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$ is equal to the operator $1/\epsilon^\alpha \,\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}\overline{x}$ if they agree for any function supplied. So, if, for all $f$ in the intersection of the domains of the operators $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$ and $1/\epsilon^\alpha \,\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}\overline{x}$, we have
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{\epsilon^\alpha} \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\overline{x}}  \text{,}  $$
the operators are equal.

Additionally, you should become familiar with the chain rule in Leibniz's notation.  This form is presented in the introductory paragraph here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule in the discussion of the equation
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}  $$
and exactly where these derivatives are evaluated.

Comment: I agree with a lot of what you said and I saw the wiki before I asked my question, but I did/do not see how exactly to pair the wiki statement to what is written. What would be z and y?

Comment: @ozeraozera : $z$ and $y$ are variables.  To use this, we have $z$ to depend on $y$ and $y$ to depend on $x$.  It should be clear that then $z$ depends on $x$.  This just tells you how the three instantaneous rates of change of those dependencies are related.

Comment: Sorry, I had meant what do $z$ and $y$ correspond in my context? $\overline{x}$ depends on $x$ but what does $x$ depend on? Nothing I think. So then when I write $\frac{d\overline{x}}{dx}$ I get $\frac{d\overline{x}}{dx}\frac{dx}{dx}$ ? This doesn't match what they write.

Comment: @ozeraozera : My answer makes clear that this is an equality of operators, not an equality of functions, so why are you expecting an equality of functions and writing expressions that are functions?  Relative to your operator, $y \mapsto \overline{x}$, $x \mapsto x$, and $z \mapsto {}$ an anonymous test function, $f$, in the discussion of showing two operators are equal.

Comment: I understand now and am not really sure why I didn't understand before. Thank you for your detailed Answer and comments.

Comment: @ozeraozera : Glad to help.  Have a good day!